# Why is $F\sin(\beta−\alpha)$ negative here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image: in this picture, F is the force applied from a pull up at an angle on an incline with friction.]

In this picture,the normal reaction is $N=mg\cos\alpha−F\sin(\beta−\alpha)$. Why do we subtract  $F\sin(\beta−\alpha)$ from $mg\cos\alpha$ ?

Comment: Are you asking why they are substracting $F\sin(\beta-\alpha)$ from $mg \cos \alpha$?

Comment: To answer your question you need to define which directions are chosen as being positive.